# image not display in admin panel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-8

Image not display why in laravel, what is the issue controller nd blade is added

**Controller**

```
try {
    $file = $request->file('image');
    $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    $imgname = uniqid().$filename;
    $input['image'] = $imgname;
    $destinationPath = public_path('upload/image/');
    $request->file('image')->move($destinationPath, $imgname);

    Auth::user();
    $article = new Article();
    $article->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $article->title = $request->get('title');
    $article->description = $request->get('description');
    $article->image = $filename;
    $article->status = $request->get('status');
    $article->save();
    $request->session()->flash('alert-success', 'article has been sucessfully created.');
    
    return back()->with('success', 'Article created successfully.');
} catch (ModelNotFoundException $exception) {
    // do task when error
    return back()->withError($exception->getMessage())->withInput();
}
```

**Blade**

```
<td>
    <img src="{{asset('/public/upload/image/'.$article->image)}}" width="500px">
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

when you use this `public_path('upload/image/');`

here you are in this path **public/upload/image/**

so when you are access in your blade by `asset()` function

the `asset()` put you in the public folder already so update your code in your blade to this:

```
 <td><img src="{{asset('/upload/image/'.$article->image)}}"
                                        width="500px"></td>
```

hopefully that is help you

Comment: It is not show actually when i click on images then show path this file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/demo/public/upload/image/629cb9b8a76f2DSCF3477.jpg and when i click on display images then show not found and show path this http://localhost/demo/upload/image/DSCF3477.jpg

Comment: because you aren't store your image in public folder

Comment: i store in this folder public/upload/image/